How to implement RabbitMQ fanout type exchange in NestJS?
I'm currently working on integrating RabbitMQ into my monolithic NestJS application for real-time inventory management as part of my e-commerce app. I want to use a fanout type exchange to broadcast stock updates to multiple queues, such as an email queue and a log queue.
My goal is to emit stock updates from the InventoryService to an exchange (stock_updates_exchange) and then fan them out to multiple queues (email_queue and log_queue). This way, the EmailService can listen for stock updates on the email_queue and send email notifications, while the LogService can listen for the same updates on the log_queue and log the events. I hope the schema below sums it all up:

even switched to golevelup's rabbitmq package but no luck, it just got even worse, blocking the HTTP gate and caused my API testing got stuck on sending request screen with no sending a response back
